# Unable to assign a item a second one

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqxwidgets

i have a strange behavior on assigning a item a second time.

Starting situation: I have a jqxTree with several items like this:

```
- apple
- oracle
- microsoft
```

I drag and drop one item in another like this:

```
-apple
|-microsoft
-oracle
```

That works fine. Now I want that the item (microsoft) would be copied and the copy should be assigned to apple and the original remains in its original position.

I have implemented the following (simple modified from the sample code ‘drag and drop’ http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxtree/index.htm#demos/jqxtree/dragdrop.htm ):

```
$('#treeA').jqxTree({ allowDrag: true, allowDrop: true, height: '300px', width: '220px', 
        dragEnd: function (item, dropItem, args, dropPosition, tree) {
            $('#treeA').jqxTree('addTo', dropItem, item, true);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Until then it works but if i drag the microsoft item a second time, the value `item` is null.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT 1:**

jsFiddle working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/mtcj7v5r/

Comment: Does `return false` alone not reject the drag?

Comment: You're right. But through the `addTo` method adds the item

Comment: Can you provide a demo on jsfiddle?

Comment: `addTo` combined with `return false` seems ambiguous. Where does the dragged item end up?

Comment: @IrvinDominin i have added a sample

Comment: @Roamer-1888 the dragged item (droppedItem) added to the item.

Comment: You don't see the ambiguity?

Comment: No, sorry, please give me a hint

Comment: I would have thought you need either `addTo` *or* `return false` but not both.

Comment: but I'm in the method `dragEnd` this method needs a return type, if i added no reurn type the framework set the return type by defaul to `null` then it's crashed inside the framework, Where did I why this happens there is no clue too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i have asked this question in the forum from the developer too and i got the following answer:

> Hello,
>
> Unfortunately, such implementation is not supported by jqxTree because
>   calling addTo in the dragEnd callback interferes with the proper
>   rendering of the widget.
>
> Best Regards, Dimitar
>
> jQWidgets team http://www.jqwidgets.com/